# Reading Mindful Minutes

Tags: ios, healthkit

Good Day,

My fitness app is coming along and I'm able to query HealthKit for other data but I'm having a difficult time getting mindful minutes.  Here is what I have:

```
//MARK: - Read Mindful Minutes
func readMindfulMinutes(date: Date) {

    guard let mindfulMinutes = HKSampleType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession) else {
        print("Sample type not available")
        return
    }

    let startDate = convertStartDate(StartDate: date)
    let endDate = convertEndDate(EndDate: date)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

    let mindfulMinutesQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: mindfulMinutes,
                                            predicate: predicate,
                                            limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                            sortDescriptors: nil) {
                                                (query, samples, error) in

                                    guard
                                        error == nil,
                                    let quantitySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
                                            print("Something went wrong: \(String(describing: error))")
                                            return
                                    }

                                        let total = quantitySamples.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.minute()) }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.userMindfulMinutes = total
                                        print("userMindfulMinutes = \(self.userMindfulMinutes)")
                                    }

    }
    HKHealthStore().execute(mindfulMinutesQuery)
}
```

}

I am always passed "Something went wrong: nil" from the print statement.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't coerce a Category sample into a Quantity sample. That's what's failing.
You have to compute the minutes from each session record.
Try;

```
  let totalMeditationTime = samples?.map(calculateMinutes).reduce(0, { $0 + $1 }) ?? 0
```

and define calculateMinutes as;

```
   func calculateMinutes(sample: HKSample) -> TimeInterval
   {
       return sample.endDate.timeIntervalSince(sample.startDate)
   }
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much for your assistance.  I'm still learning a lot about Swift and this helps me understand a little bit more.